# 今まで使っていたローカル開発環境のip: "192.168.33.10"にアクセスできなくなりました。

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Vagrantを動かしていて、`running (virtualbox)` や `vagrant provision or use the --provision`と出力されました。 `flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.`はどういう意味でしょうか？

今日の二時まではできたのに新しいボックスをインストールしたりして、新しいhostsなどを作ろうとトライするうちに今まで使ってた仮想マシンにログインできなくなりました。まず今までの状態に戻りたいです。宜しくお願い致します。

基本はドットインストールの授業をうけています。[ここ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nrel-vagrant-boxes/files/)から "CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20131103.box" というボックスをダウンロードしました。

vagrant upを実行すると、puttyでinactiveで開発環境にアクセスできなくて困っています。
原因または解決策がしりたいです。

私の行った手順は以下です。
(1)　まず今回の問題は【旧版】ローカル開発環境の構築#02 Vagrantで仮想マシンを立ち上げようをやったのがすべての問題です。つまりdev.dotinstall.comやcentos64などのローカル開発環境のホストを作ろうとしたのがすべての間違いですhttp://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_local_development_v2/24802。具体的には Vagrantの中にlocalde
vとCentoSをフォルダを作りました。そして新しいローカル開発環境の構築を見るうちに MyVagrantの中に作ればいいと授業で言っていたことを思い出し、こちらにも作成。
(2)「vagrant box add centos64box」をして仮想マシンを立ち上げるために
「vagrant init centos64box」をしてできなくてvagrant init chef/centos-6.5をしたころまでは確か覚えています。確かIP アドレスを 「192.168.33.56」はやらなかったような気がします。vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguestもしたような気がします
(3)それでdev.dotinstall.comにアクセスできないどころか普通のlacalshostにもアクセスできなくなったのでここからいろいろしました。
すると、以下のような結果になりました。

【表示されたものをコピー＆ペーストする】

原因を確かめるため、以下のようなテストを行ってみましたが、
問題の解決には至りませんでした。

(a) まずはcドライブから入りVagrantの中にlocalde
vとCentoSのフォルダを削除した。dev.dotinstall.comを作る際にd.vagrantファイルを消すとできるとあったのでvagrant関係のすべてのd.vagrantを消した。
そして新しいローカル開発授業での VirtualBox 5.1.22 以降ではエラーとなるため導入しないようにしてください。を思い出し今回つまりvagrant init chef/centos-6.5がそれにあたるとおもいhttp://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20131103.boxのファイルをcドライブから消した。本当はアンインストールしたかったのですがなかったのでアンインストールしていません。

(b) それで授業にあったようにconfig.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"も#をとりました。が画像にあるようにputtyにつながりません。宜しくお願い致します。

【エラーメッセージのコピー＆ペースト】

なお、私の環境は以下の通りです。
【マシン, メモリ量, 関連周辺機器, OS, 利用ソフト, バージョンなどを箇条書きに】
windows 10 64bit toshiba

パソコンで調べてもうやりつくしましたし、下手にやるとまたはまるのでこれ以上はしていません。

[image: ログ]

Comment: 「ボックスをダウンロードしました」という部分のリンクが抜けているようです。

Comment: ここのサイトのルールで1oo点ないとリンクをふたつ張り付けることができないと書いてありました。よって画像だけでひとつのりんくになります

Comment: `vagrant up`コマンドと`vagrant ssh`コマンドがどういうことをするコマンドなのかは分かりますか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません。これになります

Comment: http://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20131103.box

Comment: まず作ったのものを世に出すにはお金がかかりかつ安全の面でもサーバーが必要です。そこで似たような状況をつくるためにローカル開発環境を整える必要があります。

Comment: 仮想マシンを vagrant コマンドで操作するのが PowerShell、仮想マシンにログインして仮想マシンの中の処理をするのが PuTTY、と区別し、vagrant up　＝　サーバーを立ち上げる。vagrant ssh　＝住所　もしくはvagrantを中から操作するための暗証番号だと思います

Comment: この問題は解決されました。いろいろいじくりすぎてＩＰアドレスが競合した。

1.vagrant global-status

2.1.が終わった後にそのまま 
vagrant reload

3.2.が終わった後に 
ping 192.168.33.10 
としてみてその結果をスクリーンショットで添付してもらえますか？

上記を行ったあとに再度PuTTYで接続を試みていただけますか？ 
以上、ご確認ください。dotinstall様より。

Answer (score 1):

この問題は解決されました。いろいろいじくりすぎてIPアドレスが競合していたのが原因のようです。

---

*この投稿は [@Leonardo de Vinti さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34546/%e4%bb%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%a7%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%ab%e3%83%ab%e9%96%8b%e7%99%ba%e7%92%b0%e5%a2%83%e3%81%aeip-192-168-33-10%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f#comment34418_34546) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*